# trying to use React Ternary expression

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

at the return trying to use ternary expression inside of react function component to I'm trying return a div but I get an errors on the else ":" expression which says that it expects ")" "," variable declaration and declaration or statement

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const Cards = () => {
const Url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases';
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const getData = async() => {
  let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
  const response = await fetch(Url, 
    {headers: 
      {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    });
    
 const data = await response.json();
 setData(data)
 console.log(data.albums.items[0].name)
 console.log(data.albums.items)
}  

 useEffect(() => {
   getData();
 }, [])

// => the errors are in this block of code
return (
  (data && data.albums.items) 
    ? data.albums.items.map((item) => {
        const {artists, id, images, name} = item;
        return (
    <div className='card-content' style={{width: '13.5rem', height:'17rem', backgroundColor: '#242424', margin:'auto 0rem', borderRadius:'0.75rem'}}>
   <div key={id} >
       <img src={images[0].url}/>
   </div>
      <h4>{name}</h4>
      <p>{`by ${artists.name}`}</p> 
      </div>
    : <p>Unreachable</p> );
       
}))
// <= the errors are in this block of code
}
```

Comment: Try to fix the indentation on the file and you'll be able to detect the error in no time. Right now, the indentation is not helping you detect the extra or missing { or ).

Comment: Also, since it's really hard to read such lengthy ternary operations, try to move the first part into a function, in order for the ternary to be more readable, e.g. (data && data.albums.items) ? getAlbums() : <p>Unreachable</p>;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is problem where you place

```
: <p>Unreachable</p>
```

the code should be like this

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';

export const Cards = () => {
const Url = 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/browse/new-releases';
const [data, setData] = useState([])

const getData = async() => {
  let token = window.localStorage.getItem('token')
  const response = await fetch(Url, 
    {headers: 
      {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`},
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    });
    
 const data = await response.json();
 setData(data)
 console.log(data.albums.items[0].name)
 console.log(data.albums.items)
}  

 useEffect(() => {
   getData();
 }, [])

// => the errors are in this block of code
return (
  (data && data.albums.items) 
    ? data.albums.items.map((item) => {
        const {artists, id, images, name} = item;
        return (
    <div className='card-content' style={{width: '13.5rem', height:'17rem', backgroundColor: '#242424', margin:'auto 0rem', borderRadius:'0.75rem'}}>
   <div key={id} >
       <img src={images[0].url}/>
   </div>
      <h4>{name}</h4>
      <p>{`by ${artists.name}`}</p> 
      </div>)
     
       
}): <p>Unreachable</p>)
// <= the errors are in this block of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in your code. That piece:

```
: <p>Unreachable</p>
```

is inside `map` callback which is not correct.
Try to always keep an indent and properly format your code to avoid such errors in future.

Here is your code, but properly formatted.

```
    return (
      (data && data.albums.items)
        ? data.albums.items.map((item) => {
          const {
            artists, id, images, name,
          } = item;
          return (
            <div
              className="card-content"
              style={{
                width: '13.5rem', height: '17rem', backgroundColor: '#242424', margin: 'auto 0rem', borderRadius: '0.75rem',
              }}
            >
              <div key={id}>
                <img src={images[0].url} />
              </div>
              <h4>{name}</h4>
              <p>{`by ${artists.name}`}</p>
            </div>
          );
        })
        : <p>Unreachable</p>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

According to @jihad.khorfan answer

Here is the wrong & working code with prettify

Wrong Code

```
  // => the errors are in this block of code
  return data && data.albums.items ? (
    data.albums.items.map((item) => {
      const { artists, id, images, name } = item;
      return (
        <div
          className='card-content'
          style={{
            width: "13.5rem",
            height: "17rem",
            backgroundColor: "#242424",
            margin: "auto 0rem",
            borderRadius: "0.75rem",
          }}
        >
          <div key={id}>
            <img src={images[0].url} />
          </div>
          <h4>{name}</h4>
          <p>{`by ${artists.name}`}</p>
        </div>
      : <p>Unreachable</p>

  }))

  // <= the errors are in this block of code
```

Working Code

```
  // => the errors are in this block of code
  return data && data.albums.items ? (
    data.albums.items.map((item) => {
      const { artists, id, images, name } = item;
      return (
        <div
          className='card-content'
          style={{
            width: "13.5rem",
            height: "17rem",
            backgroundColor: "#242424",
            margin: "auto 0rem",
            borderRadius: "0.75rem",
          }}
        >
          <div key={id}>
            <img src={images[0].url} />
          </div>
          <h4>{name}</h4>
          <p>{`by ${artists.name}`}</p>
        </div>
      );
    })
  ) : (
    <p>Unreachable</p>
  );
  // <= the errors are in this block of code
```

Answer (score -1):

You should put your ternary code inside curly braces e.g.

```
{ showMe ? <span>Me</span> : <span>You</span>}
```

and maybe refactor your code more like this:

```
return (
 <>
 {data && data.albums.items ? data.albums.items.map((item) => 
   <div>
     <div key={item.id}>
       {item.name}
     </div>
     <div>
       {item.artist}
     </div>
   </div>) : <p>Unreachable</p>
 }
 </>
)
```

Notice I changed the data format a bit as I was testing it.